# How do I add a picklist value to the LeadSource field of the default Contact object using the rest API?

Tags: salesforce

I'm working on a Salesforce integration and I would like to add a new option to the picklist LeadSource when creating Contacts. Our integration uses the REST API exclusively.

I've been banging on this for awhile and feel like I've gotten close with the tooling API but I can't quite get there.

First I use the tooling API to get the LeadSource value set

GET /services/data/v49.0/tooling/query
q=SELECT id,durableid,metadata,fullname,masterlabel FROM StandardValueSet where masterlabel='LeadSource'

Then I try to patch it with:

PATCH /services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/StandardValueSet/

I have the data I am sending with the patch passing all the validation but now I am stuck on the following response:

Response: [{"message":"bad id LeadSource","errorCode":"MALFORMED_ID","fields":[]}]

If I try the Id instead of the DurableId I get a similar response.

Answer (score 0):

`/services/data/v53.0/tooling/sobjects/StandardValueSet/describe` says it's not createable, updateable, I don't think you can do it this way. Describing `PicklistValueInfo` also doesn't say much.

You might have to do it by the book, with a proper tooling api deployment.